# Querying other collection inside forEach

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I want to do something like:

```
db.ratings.find().forEach(function(doc){

  var item = db.items.find({_id: doc.item_id})
  var ry = item.detail.ry
  db.ratings.update(doc,{$set: {itd: ry}})

})
```

The problem is that `db.items.find({_id: doc.item_id})` is returning something to which I cannot call document properties directly. Which would it be the correct way of doing this? Thanks!

db.items:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5461c8f0426f727f16000000"),
    "n" : "The Shawshank Redemption",
    "detail" : {
      "ry": 1992
    }
}
```

Comment: use db.items.findOne({_id: doc.item_id});

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `find()` function returns a `cursor`, you need to iterate it:

> When the find() method “returns documents,” the method is actually
>   returning a cursor to the documents

Your code, updated:

```
db.ratings.find().forEach(function(doc){

  db.items.find({_id: doc.item_id}).forEach(function(item){
   var ry = item.detail.ry;
   db.ratings.update(doc,{$set: {itd: ry}});
   })
})
```

or you may use `findOne()` which returns one of the matching documents.

```
db.ratings.find().forEach(function(doc){

  var item = db.items.findOne({_id: doc.item_id})
  var ry = item.detail.ry
  db.ratings.update(doc,{$set: {itd: ry}})

})
```

Comment: @BatScream How to handle Duplicate Error?

Comment: I tried for MongoDb: `schema.find().forEach()` and got `not a function`... Is this still relevant?